# Streams data from multiple while loops

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, psutil

I am using psutil to analyze the open_files() at any given point of time. As soon as program creates a file with a specific extension of interest (could be .xlsx, .csv, .docx, .dat), I want to save the file in another directory before it is modified and then perform sequential operations on it.

Right now I am using nested while loops, but then if the program outputs multiple files, they aren't detected as the loop might not have processed the previous file.

```
files_of_interest = []
process = psutil.Process(pid)
while True:
    for i in process.open_files():
        print(i.path) # warning, traffic in terminal
        if i.path.endswith(".xslx"):
            print("This is a file of interest")
            files_of_interest.append(i.path)

# Second while loop

safe_location = "C:\\safe"
while True:
    if len(files_of_interest) > 0:
        try:
            os.rename(files_of_interest[0], files_of_interest[0]) # check file in use
            # temporarily copy to safe location for processing
            shutil.copy(files_of_interest[0], safe_location)
            files_of_interest.pop()
            break
        except OSError:
            continue

# Third to process safe folder items one by one

while True:
    if len(files_in_safe_location) > 0:
        do_something()
```

I need to optimize this, run the while loops in parallel and get the best possible outcome without any race conditions (as far as possible).

I know how to do this in dart (isolates) and nodejs (web workers), but the process in python seems very different since I assumed python does not have streams like async functionality (dynamically react to changes in instance data).

Comment: Your starting point for this should probably be multithreading but beware... there are sharks in the water due to timing issues. Observing a new file and moving it **before** it's modified is virtually impossible to do reliably. Also, if you move it then what do you think will happen to the program that's trying to modify it?

Comment: @Pingu Typically, the file I'm interested in won't be opened immediately upon creation. That window of approximately 1 second is what I'll have. That is why I want to initiate copying it before the window expires. Sadly many of windows programs create the file beforehand and then write data to it. I can pause the processes that try to access the file also, do you think that might help? I've been looking into multiprocessing, but while loops are said to not be very reliable or stable with the memory they take.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **asyncio** library and use the **async** and **await** function. Example:

```
import asyncio

async def loop1():
    # put the code for while loop1

async def loop2():
    # put the code for while loop2

async def loop3():
    # put the code for while loop3

await asyncio.gather(loop1(), loop2(), loop3())
```

Comment: This will sequentially gather the loops one by one asynchronously. I want to run them parallelly together. Essentially, async will run loop1, then loop2 and then loop3 and gather them together, which is not my intention